# determining the starting speed for an accelerated animation (in flash/actionscript but it's a math question)

Tags: flash, math, actionscript, physics

This question burns my brain.

I have an object on a plane, but for the sake of simplicity let's work just on a single dimension, thus the object has a starting position xs. I know the ending position xe. The object has to move from starting to ending position with an accelerated (acceleration=a) movement. I know the velocity the object has to have at the ending position (=ve). In my special case the ending speed is zero, but of course I need a general formula. The only unknown is the starting velocity vs.

The objects starts with vs in xs and ends with ve in xe, moving along a space x with an acceleration a in a time t.

Since I'm working with flash, space is expressed in pixels, time is expressed in frames (but you can reason in terms of seconds, it's easy to convert knowing the frames-per-second).

In the animation loop (think onEnterFrame) I compute the new velocity and the new position with (a=0.4 for example):

```
vx *= a (same for vy)
x += vx (same for y)
```

I want the entire animation to last, say, 2 seconds, which at 30 fps is 60 frames. 
Now you know that in 60 frames my object has to move from xs to xe with a constant deceleration so that the ending speed is 0. How do I compute the starting speed vs?

Maybe there's a simpler way to do this in Flash, but I am now interested in the math/physics behind this.

edit as per DSM answer.

I've tried to apply his suggestions:

```
var vx:Number;
var a  = -0.5; 
var xs:Number = 0;
var xe:Number = Stage.width;
var mc:MovieClip;
var keyListener = {};
var startTime:Number;

init();

function init()
{
    mc = attachMovie("pallino",  "p1", 0);
    mc._y = Stage.height/2;

    Key.addListener(keyListener);
}
```

Acceleration is -0.5, starting x is 0, ending x is the stage width. I attach a movieclip to the middle of the stage and then wait for a keypress. Then:

```
keyListener.onKeyDown = function()
{
    var k = Key.getCode();

    mc._x = xs;
    vx = 2 * (xe - xs) / 60;
    trace("vx:"+vx);

    startTime = new Date().getTime();
    onEnterFrame = startAnimation;
}
```

In the keypress event I set the starting velocity; here I use 60 for the time because my stage is set at 30 fps and I want the animation to happen in 2 seconds. Finally the animation is:

```
function startAnimation()
{
    trace("running, vx:" + vx);

    mc._x += vx;
    vx += a;

    if ( mc._x >= xe )
    {
        trace("stopping because clip is on target position");
        stopAnimation();
        return;
    }

    if ( vx <= 0 )
    {
        trace("stopping because speed is too slow");
        stopAnimation();
        return;
    }

}

function stopAnimation()
{
    this.onEnterFrame = null;
    var secsElapsed:Number = ( new Date().getTime() - startTime) / 1000;
    trace(secsElapsed);

}
```

The animation stops because the speed is too slow (less than zero) before the clip reaches the destination x. Why??

Comment: Not an answer, obviously, but have you considered using a tween engine, like Tweener ( http://code.google.com/p/tweener/ )  or TweenLite ( https://www.greensock.com/tweenlite/ )?  These will allow you use a number of mathematical curves to smoothly animate over a number of frames, or time in seconds, and you could forget about the math almost entirely.

Comment: I have created a similar tween library, with elastic movements of all sorts, but now I am really interested in the physics behind this thing because it hurts me I can't find a solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

v = v_0 + a*t

If you know v (final velocity), a (acceleration) and t (time), then v_0 (initial velocity) comes naturally:

v_0 = v - a*t

(You can also derive it from equation 1 in DSM's answer if you know x and x_0, but this is simpler. If you do both, the results should match)

EDIT: Actually, I think your problem has too many constrains, and is therefore unsolvable. You need another variable that can change. If you arbitrate ("know") a, t, and v, Then v_0 is defined as v-a*t. If you then arbitrate x_0, then x_f is defined (or vice-versa). But you want to arbitrate both! So, choose another variable that can actually vary, i.e., that doesn't matter that much to you, and then your problem will become solvable.

EDIT2: The asker said in the comments that acceleration can vary. Thus, isolating v_0 in DSM's equations 1 and 2, then solving for a, we have:

a=(2*v/t) + 2*(x_0-x_f)/(t^2)

Then v_0 is v - a*t. This does not require that v_f is zero.

EDIT3: The failure of the code edited into the question might be due to numeric imprecision. I suggest you allow for a small tolerance when comparing current and target position. (Or just print the position difference to make sure it's very small, then decide the code is working well enough for use.)

Comment: Agreed.  If you stick with the constant-acceleration model, fix x_0 at t=0 and x_f and v_f=0 at t=t_f, you have no freedom left.  a and v_0 are both given by the third and fourth equations I posted.

Comment: I can vary the acceleration, but once computed it must remain constant during the movement. I can also live with the final velocity to be near 0, say 0.001. I think one problem is that the frames-per-second is not a precise value, it is just a hint to the flash engine. If I set 24fps and compute vx = 2 * (xe - xs) / (2 * 24), then on my machine the speed becomes too small before target is reached, but if I compute vx = 2 * (xe - xs) / (2 * 23.7) which could be an *average* real fps, then the animation stops quite near its target.

Answer (score 1):

Let x, v, a be instantaneous position, velocity, and acceleration, and t the time.  Use _0 for the initial and _f for the final.

We have at a general time t

(eq. 1)  **x = x_0 + v_0 t + 1/2 a t^2**  for constant acceleration a,

and

(eq. 2) **v = v_0 + a t**

At the end, i.e. t = t_f, you want x = x_f and v = v_f = 0.  The latter condition gives v_0 = -a t_f (insert v = 0 into (eq. 2)).  Inserting this into (eq. 1) at time t=t_f gives

**a = 2 (x_0-x_f)/t_f^2**

and thus

**v_0 = 2 (x_f - x_0) / t_f**

which is simply a derivation of the basic kinematic equation saying that the average of initial and final velocity is the average velocity ((v_0+v_f)/2 = d/t, again for constant acceleration) where we've set v_f = 0.  [Actually, you can get the above within a constant factor just by noting the units: velocity has units of [length/time], so the final answer should probably look like the displacement divided by the time..]

I think using the incorrect formula (v *= 'a' ) produces a smoother animation because that equation doesn't correspond to a constant acceleration (which has a jerk of zero, where jerk is the time derivative of acceleration the same way that acceleration is the time derivative of velocity) but a variable one which is smoother (because v ~ 'a'^t).

If you really do want a smoother, non-constant acceleration -- i.e. the one given by your v *= k approach --  it's straightforward to work out the details in that case too, but this was the easier one to explain..

Update: oh, what the heck.  If v = v_0 * k^t, then as Al Brown noted, the velocity isn't ever going to go to zero in your situation, so you'll have to live with some small v_f > 0.  We then have v_f = v_0 * k^t_f as one equation and x_f = x_0 + v_0 k^(t_f) / log(t_f) -- integrate the velocity equation to get this -- as the other; solving is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: I tried but something is going wrong. I'm editing the question to explain.

Answer (score 0):

From what you are saying `ve = Math.pow(a, frames) * vs` so `vs = ve / Math.pow(a, frames)`.

However that won't work with ve = 0 (as 0 * X = 0), so you will have to try it for ve = 0.0000001 or something close.

On an additional note acceleration should treat velocity in the same way as velocity does to position.
`x += vx`,
`vx += a` ( a < 0 for deceleration)
In this case `vs = ve - a*frames`

Comment: You are right about the additional note, but I have noticed that multiplying velocity by a proper acceleration, instead of adding, makes the animation smoother. I don't know why.

Comment: How comes your formulas don't take into account the distance, that is xe and xs?